# SQL select only unique records basic on first column

Tags: sql, select

I got table with:

```
Code Price 
A |  200
A |  199
B |  300
B |  320
C |  400
C |  410
```

How to select these data to get

```
A |  200
B |  300
C |  400
```

What I came up with was

```
SELECT DISTINCT
```

but it doesn't work and if I trying to use

```
GROUP BY CODE
```

I get:

Column 'Table.Code' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Thank you in advance for any tips.

Comment: What is your reason for picking the quoted range of rows as the "correct" result? SQL usually needs reproducable rules. There is no "implicit" order in SQL tables, so you must specify by which column you want things to be sorted, in case you were thinking of "picking the first of each" row.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #12 (code varchar(100),price int)

insert into #12 values ('a',200),('b',199),('B',300),('b',320)


SELECT * FROM (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY CODE) AS RN FROM #12) AS TN
WHERE RN =1
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of delivering *a* result would be:

```
Select code, min(price) minprice, max(price) maxprice
from Table
Group by code
```

This will get min and max prices for each code. Your *requested* result has both, min and max values in it. Can you provide a *reliable rule* (in plain English) for that particular result set?

If you want "the first" price listed for each code then your table needs something like an auto-incremented index `idx` (or timestamp) column. Having this column you can use @Ramji's or @Gordy's `ROW_NUMBER()` solution in a modified form:

```
;with first_price_per_code as (
  select Code, Price, r = row_number()
  over (partition by Code order by idx)
  from Table
)
select Code, Price from first_price_per_code 
where r = 1
```

The above code is SQL-Server specific, but similar stuff can be done in Mysql or other RDBMS too.

Otherwise - *without* having a rule - the following would also produce your result (→ this is just a JOKE!!!):

```
select code, round(avg(price),-2) price
from Table group by code
```

Answer (score 0):

sql doesn't have an aggregate for "appears first", but there's a hack:

```
with first_price_per_code as (
    select Code, Price, r = row_number() over (partition by Code order by (select null))
    from Table
) select Code, Price from first_price_per_code where r = 1
```

the behavior is undefined and unsupported of course, good luck!